# The code is start of sample data for Joomla Radon template. Syntax error appears in line 9. Unfortunately I did not find what is wrong

Tags: mysql, joomla, mysql-error-1064, acymailing

Database: `radon`
Table structure for table `#__acymailing_config`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__acymailing_config`;
CREATE TABLE `#__acymailing_config` (
  `namekey` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Dumping data for table `#__acymailing_config`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a table name like `#__acymailing_config`.
Just put your prefix instead of `#__`

cheers and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately meanwhile I gave up and used other template which is working fine. The table with same name is also used.

Comment: Yes joomla knows the prefix and replaces the #__ .i thought you want to generate the table manually and that wouldn't work :)